# how to parse GNU Screen session list?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, gnu, gnu-screen

how are one supposed to programmatically parse GNU Screen session lists? i am using PHP here, but an answer in any programming language would be helpful. i've tried doing it myself with regex and seems i'm pretty close, but it won't correctly parse sessions with parentheses-in-the-name (which is an edge-case supported by GNU Screen)

this

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
function screen_list_sessions(): array
{
    if (1) {
        // test code
        $raw = '
There are screens on:
        2064.screen with parenthesis in name ( this is stupid ) (10/02/2021 12:07:22 PM)        (Detached)
        1996.test session with spaces (10/02/2021 12:00:35 PM)        (Detached)
        1985.testSessionWithDuplicateName       (10/02/2021 12:00:23 PM)        (Detached)
        1974.testSessionWithDuplicateName       (10/02/2021 12:00:16 PM)        (Detached)
        1963.testSessionWithDuplicateName       (10/02/2021 12:00:09 PM)        (Detached)
        1871.testscreen (10/02/2021 11:59:23 AM)        (Detached)
6 Sockets in /run/screen/S-root.

';
    } else {
        $raw = shell_exec('screen -list');
    }
    $matches = [];
    $match_count = preg_match_all('/^\s+(?<session_id>\d+)\\.(?<session_name>.*?)\((?<session_creation_date>[\s\S]+?)\)\s+\((?<session_state>[\s\S]+?)\)\s*?$/mu', $raw, $matches);
    $ret = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $match_count; ++$i) {
        $ret[] = [
            "session_id" => $matches["session_id"][$i],
            "session_name" => $matches['session_name'][$i],
            "session_creation_date" => $matches["session_creation_date"][$i],
            "session_state" => $matches["session_state"][$i]
        ];
    }
    return $ret;
}
var_export(screen_list_sessions());
```

returns

```php
$ php test.php
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '2064',
    'session_name' => 'screen with parenthesis in name ',
    'session_creation_date' => ' this is stupid ',
    'session_state' => '10/02/2021 12:07:22 PM)        (Detached',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '1996',
    'session_name' => 'test session with spaces ',
    'session_creation_date' => '10/02/2021 12:00:35 PM',
    'session_state' => 'Detached',
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '1985',
    'session_name' => 'testSessionWithDuplicateName       ',
    'session_creation_date' => '10/02/2021 12:00:23 PM',
    'session_state' => 'Detached',
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '1974',
    'session_name' => 'testSessionWithDuplicateName       ',
    'session_creation_date' => '10/02/2021 12:00:16 PM',
    'session_state' => 'Detached',
  ),
  4 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '1963',
    'session_name' => 'testSessionWithDuplicateName       ',
    'session_creation_date' => '10/02/2021 12:00:09 PM',
    'session_state' => 'Detached',
  ),
  5 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '1871',
    'session_name' => 'testscreen ',
    'session_creation_date' => '10/02/2021 11:59:23 AM',
    'session_state' => 'Detached',
  ),
)
```

edit: tried without regex, seems i got even closer, this

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
function screen_list_sessions(): array
{
    if (1) {
        // test code
        $raw = '
There are screens on:
        2064.screen with parenthesis in name ( this is stupid ) (10/02/2021 12:07:22 PM)        (Detached)
        1996.test session with spaces (10/02/2021 12:00:35 PM)        (Detached)
        1985.testSessionWithDuplicateName       (10/02/2021 12:00:23 PM)        (Detached)
        1974.testSessionWithDuplicateName       (10/02/2021 12:00:16 PM)        (Detached)
        1963.testSessionWithDuplicateName       (10/02/2021 12:00:09 PM)        (Detached)
        1871.testscreen (10/02/2021 11:59:23 AM)        (Detached)
6 Sockets in /run/screen/S-root.

';
    } else {
        $raw = shell_exec('screen -list');
    }
    $raw = implode("\n", array_filter(explode("\n", $raw), function (string $line): bool {
        // remove uninteresting lines; only lines that start with spaces are interesting..
        $trimmed = ltrim($line);
        if ($trimmed === $line) {
            return false;
        }
        if (strlen($trimmed) < 1) {
            // empty lines are also uninteresting
            return false;
        }
        // interesting line
        return true;
    }));
    $ret = [];
    $lines = explode("\n", $raw);
    foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {
        $current = [];
        $lastParStart = strrpos($line, '(');
        if ($lastParStart === false) {
            throw new \LogicException("line without \"(\": {$line}");
        }
        $lastParEnd = strrpos($line, ')');
        if ($lastParEnd === false) {
            throw new \LogicException("line without \")\": {$line}");
        }
        $current['session_state'] = substr($line, $lastParStart + strlen('('), $lastParEnd - $lastParStart - strlen(')'));
        $line = substr($line, 0, $lastParStart);
        $lastParStart = strrpos($line, '(');
        if ($lastParStart === false) {
            throw new \LogicException("line without 2nd \"(\": {$line}");
        }
        $lastParEnd = strrpos($line, ')');
        if ($lastParEnd === false) {
            throw new \LogicException("line without 2nd \")\": {$line}");
        }
        $current['session_creation_date'] = substr($line, $lastParStart + strlen('('), $lastParEnd - $lastParStart - strlen(')'));
        $line = substr($line, 0, $lastParStart - strlen("\t"));
        $dotPos = strpos($line, '.');
        if (false === $dotPos) {
            throw new \LogicException("");
        }
        $current['session_id'] = trim(substr($line, 0, $dotPos));
        // using trim() here probably means we won't 100% support sessions whose names starts or ends with space...
        $current['session_name'] = trim(substr($line, $dotPos + strlen(".")));
        // just put keys in pretty-ish order
        $current = [
            "session_id" => $current['session_id'],
            "session_name" => $current['session_name'],
            "session_state" => $current['session_state'],
            "session_creation_date" => $current['session_creation_date'],
        ];
        $ret[] = $current;
    }
    return $ret;
}
var_export(screen_list_sessions());
```

prints

```php
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '2064',
    'session_name' => 'screen with parenthesis in name ( this is stupid )',
    'session_state' => 'Detached',
    'session_creation_date' => '10/02/2021 12:07:22 PM',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '1996',
    'session_name' => 'test session with spaces',
    'session_state' => 'Detached',
    'session_creation_date' => '10/02/2021 12:00:35 PM',
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '1985',
    'session_name' => 'testSessionWithDuplicateName',
    'session_state' => 'Detached',
    'session_creation_date' => '10/02/2021 12:00:23 PM',
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '1974',
    'session_name' => 'testSessionWithDuplicateName',
    'session_state' => 'Detached',
    'session_creation_date' => '10/02/2021 12:00:16 PM',
  ),
  4 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '1963',
    'session_name' => 'testSessionWithDuplicateName',
    'session_state' => 'Detached',
    'session_creation_date' => '10/02/2021 12:00:09 PM',
  ),
  5 =>
  array (
    'session_id' => '1871',
    'session_name' => 'testscreen',
    'session_state' => 'Detached',
    'session_creation_date' => '10/02/2021 11:59:23 AM',
  ),
)
```

(this approach does not support parsing screen sessions whose names starts or ends with spaces, though, i think)

Comment: Try `^\s+(?<session_id>\d+)\.(?<session_name>.*?)\((?<session_creation_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M)\)\s+\((?<session_state>[\s\S]+?)\)\s*?$` See https://regex101.com/r/VU23am/1

Answer (score 1):

You might change the pattern to make the `session_creation_date` more specific. You could also omit matching the spaces after by session_name by matching optional whitespace chars `s*` after (outside) of the capture group.

```
^\s+(?<session_id>\d+)\.(?<session_name>.*?)\s*\((?<session_creation_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M)\)\s+\((?<session_state>[\s\S]+?)\)\s*?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EsCHyN/1/)

A less strict pattern could be using 2 [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^()]+` at the end of the pattern to match the text between parenthesis

```
^\s+(?<session_id>\d+)\.(?<session_name>.*?)\s*\((?<session_creation_date>[^()]+)\)\s+\((?<session_state>[^()]+)\)\s*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tPvAPa/1/)

**Note** that in your pattern `[\s\S]` matches any character including newlines which could lead to matching too much.

The `\s*` could also match newlines, and the `\s*?` at the end of the pattern does not have to be non greedy as it matches until the end of the string already.

Comment: that seems perfect, thanks! but i wouldn't put it past GNU Screen to take the date format from the LC_TIME environment variable, wonder if it could be made more different-date-formats-tolerant

Comment: @hanshenrik What you might also do is match all between parenthesis using 2 negated character classes instead. `^\s+(?<session_id>\d+)\.(?<session_name>.*?)\s*\((?<session_creation_date>[^()]+)\)\s+\((?<session_state>[^()]+)\)\s*$` See https://regex101.com/r/tPvAPa/1

Comment: thanks, that 2nd regex looks safer (when up against different LC_TIME formats) than your first regex ^^ think you could add that to the answer?

Comment: @hanshenrik I have added that one as well.

Comment: @hanshenrikhan if you plan on bloating the pattern with named capture groups, then rely on them when generating your return array. https://3v4l.org/dKRSK